# Sort a table by the name in a cell

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table that is organized with folders.  I have added a context menu where they can move a row to a different folder.  I have the code working to change the cells of the selected row correctly but now need to resort my table so the row will show in the new folder.

```
var sort = $("#hiddenresult tr.events").sort(function (a, b) {
     return ($(a).text().toLowerCase() == $(b).text().toLowerCase()) ? 0 :     ($(a).text().toLowerCase() < $(b).text().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
                                        });
$('#hiddenresult').html(sort);
```

I have the above code which sorts the table by the first cell.  Is there a way to get this to select a cell by class to sort on?  I tried `$(a).find('td.folderName')`... but reading on here find is slow and I didn't get an error with it but the table didn't sort.  The row showed up in the table in the previous position with the new folder name.  I tried `$(a 'td.folderName')` but the compiler didn't like that code.

http://jsfiddle.net/qDZXh shows is simple table to show what I am looking for, trying to sort on the 3rd column (folder name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting itself isn't as slow as the browser re-rendering the table every time something changes. I recommend pulling the table out of the DOM, sorting it, then putting it back in place so the browser only renders it once.

```
var trs = $('#hiddenresult tbody tr.events').detach();
trs.sort(function(a, b) {
     var atxt = $(a).find('td.folderName').text().toLowerCase();
     var btxt = $(b).find('td.folderName').text().toLowerCase();
     return (atxt >= btxt) - (atxt <= btxt);
});
$('#hiddenresult tbody').append(trs);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qDZXh/2/

Edit: detaching and appending will make the table flicker or disappear while the table is sorting. Alternatively you can use `.clone(true)` to copy the tbody with all of its events etc, then use `.replaceWith` at the end to swap them out.

Comment: My code works fine with the fiddle. If your page is refreshing, then there's something going on that you're not telling us about.