# Rearranging objects in page

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, sorting

I am building a Django web app and I have a list of objects that I want to rearrange with a radio button. I want the user to be able to sort them with Ranadom, Alphabetical and Date order. I don't mind reloading the page.

Should I: 1. Use post to reload with the parameter, 2. Use ajax and reload the content in the container, 3. Just use jQuery to do the sorting without going back to the server, 4. Something I haven't thought of.

Which way would you go about it? Any directions of sample code would be really appreciated.

Also I'm planning on using Masonry or Django Endless Pagination and there will be 100-200 objects with a thumbnail and some text that will be retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery, without hitting the server. I just answered something like this earlier today: [Sort a table by the name in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050459/sort-a-table-by-the-name-in-a-cell)